# How to redirect apps from browser to safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, deeplink

How to redirect apps from browser to safari?

on android, I do this if a user opens my site through a browser built-in for example in FB or a Telegram, then he immediately redirects to google chrome where my site opens
Location: `googlechrome: // navigate? Url = $ url`

how to do the same on ios you just threw on safari?

Comment: have you got it working?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a deep link

you go to the properties Xcode and add a associated domains: 
for example applinks:flink.page.link <-(flink.page.link should be your url)

then in the appDelegate put this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            //open a view or something else
        }
        return false
    }
```

for more information use this : [ios deep link](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97)

Comment: i am using html+js and pwa.